# increasing the resolution of the p value on a Tukey test in R

Tags: r, p-value, tukey

I performed a Tukey HSD test in R, and I want to see the p-value of one of the comparisons. When I run the Tukey test, my p values are so small that on the table they just read as "0.0000000". I need to know what the actual value is, even if it is so small that it rounds off to 0. How can I do that? The ANOVA generates a p value of 2.2e-16.

```
data <- data.frame(temp=c(three,four,fif,six,sev),
                   year=factor(rep(c("2013","2014","2015","2016","2017"),
                                   times=c(length(three),length(four),length(fif),length(six),length(sev)))))
final <- aov(temp~year,data=data)
anova(final)
tuk <- TukeyHSD(final)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try changing options?

```
options("scipen" = 100, "digits" = 22)
```

When you're done, set it back to default.

```
options("scipen" = 0, "digits" = 7)
```